# is there a way to use logger in application.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For Rails4 application, is there a way to use logger in the application.rb?

I need to print out some log information here before anything else.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, tried logger, Rails.logger, all doesn;t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, "log/configuration.log")))
logger.info("Some log entry")
```

If you want to redirect all log output to the console you may try:

```
logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
logger.info("Some log entry to the console")
```

or for simply inspection of something:

```
puts "Another log entry to the console"
```

Comment: how can I log to console?

Comment: @AdamLee see improved answer.